# NULLS LAST function for Hive

Tags: sql, hive, null

I have the following algorithm for selecting records, following the example written below, the following records should be selected.

1. If "issuedate" is an empty column, then take "publid", which has
   more "inn".
2. If "issuedate" is not all equal, then we take "issuedate" = last date.
3. If "issuedate" are all equal, then we take "operdate" = last date.
4. If "issuedate" are equal and operdate are equal, then we take "publid", which has more "inn".

I wrote a code in oracle and wanted to run it in hive, but an error appears. I think this is because of the NULLS LAST function. Please tell me how to change the NULLS LAST function in the code to the correct one for Hive.

Example

```
| inn | publid | clusterid | issuedate | operdate |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 333 |   1    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 222 |   1    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 333 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 | 
| 222 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 111 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 123 |   1    |     1     |  01-01-21 |          |
| 456 |   1    |     1     |  01-01-21 |          |
| 123 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          |
| 456 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          | 
| 789 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          |
| 123 |   3    |     1     |  02-01-21 |          |
| 456 |   3    |     1     |  02-01-21 |          |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 123 |   1    |     1     |           | 01-01-21 |
| 456 |   1    |     1     |           | 01-01-21 |
| 123 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 |
| 456 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 | 
| 789 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 |
| 123 |   3    |     1     |           | 02-01-21 |
| 456 |   3    |     1     |           | 02-01-21 |
```

Result

```
| inn | publid | clusterid | issuedate | operdate |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 333 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 222 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
| 111 |   2    |    12     |  01-01-21 | 05-01-21 |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 123 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          |
| 456 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          |
| 789 |   2    |     1     |  03-01-21 |          |
|-----|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|
| 123 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 |
| 456 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 |
| 789 |   2    |     1     |           | 03-01-21 |
```

> ```
>     SELECT inn,
>        publid,
>        clusterid,
>        issuedate,
>        operdate
> FROM   (
>   SELECT inn,
>          publid,
>          clusterid,
>          issuedate,
>          operdate,
>          DENSE_RANK() OVER (
>            PARTITION BY clusterid
>            ORDER     BY COALESCE( issuedate, operdate ) DESC NULLS LAST,
>                         cnt DESC
>          ) AS rnk
>   FROM   (
>     SELECT t.*,
>            COUNT(inn) OVER (PARTITION BY publid) cnt
>     FROM   table_name t
>     WHERE  clusterid is not null
>   )
> )
> WHERE  rnk = 1;
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add one more expression to the ORDER BY

Replace this:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE( issuedate, operdate ) DESC NULLS LAST
```

with this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN COALESCE(issuedate, operdate) is NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, --acts as NULLS LAST
         COALESCE( issuedate, operdate ) DESC
```

Also according to this Jira: [HIVE-12994](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12994)   currently NULLS FIRST is the default for ASC order, and NULLS LAST for DESC order and probably you can remove NULLS LAST and it will work as default for DESC order. It needs to be carefully checked.